# statsmodels anova_lm returns PR>F 0.0: How to change the number of decimals?

Tags: python, statsmodels, anova, p-value, significance

I'm performing ANOVA on a pandas dataframe using `statsmodels anova_lm`.

The returned significance level `PR>F` is `0.0`. I assume this is a rounded value, but rounded at how many decimal places?

Is there a way to specify the number of decimal places in `statsmodels`?

my code:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import statsmodels.api as sm

formula = 'consensus_rate ~ C(strategy) + np.power(nr_clues,' + str(exp) +') +  shared_ratio + primacy_weight + edges_per_node '
lm = ols(formula, data=bigdf).fit()
sm.stats.anova_lm(lm, typ=2)
```

returns

```
>>>>                           sum_sq      df             F  PR(>F)
C(strategy)              1.909980e+06     3.0  15196.209763     0.0
np.power(nr_clues, 0.1)  5.159021e+05     1.0  12313.884367     0.0
shared_ratio             7.383109e+05     1.0  17622.480378     0.0
primacy_weight           2.099998e+05     1.0   5012.410347     0.0
edges_per_node           8.457493e+04     1.0   2018.689015     0.0
Residual                 3.013158e+05  7192.0           NaN     NaN
```

Comment: `anova_lm` returns a pandas DataFrame. So you have all the pandas options to display and work with the results.

Answer (score 0):

`PR(>F)` is probably smaller than `0.000000`

Looking at other `statsmodels` anova tables, it seems `statsmodels` displays floats with 6 decimals.

For example:

```
              df  sum_sq     mean_sq          F    PR(>F)
C(Fitness)   2.0   672.0  336.000000  16.961538  0.000041
Residual    21.0   416.0   19.809524        NaN       NaN
```

sourced from: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/interactions_anova.html